# use colored compiler output in gitlab CI with ninja

Tags: gitlab-ci, ninja

When using `-fdiagnostics-color` in my compiler options, I receive colorized output in the compiler output (gcc and clang). This also works with ninja when I run on my local computer. Doing the same in a gitlab-CI, the colors are stripped away. Is there a way to get colored compiler output in a gitlab CI?

I tried make instead of ninja and there the colors appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from [ninja's output handling](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/blame/master/src/build.cc#L146) (Ninja must interfere with the output to avoid that concurrent processes mix their outputs). While gcc/clang even in the gitlab-CI issue colored output, ninja determines if the output goes to a usual user terminal or a logfile and removes the colors. This is discussed on the ninja github page:

for the smart-terminal detection and color preservation:
[issue](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/916) [pull request](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/pull/1268)

and somewhat related:
[another issue](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1214) [another pull request](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/pull/1230)

**EDIT**: as of [this](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/commit/bf7107bb864d0383028202e3f4a4228c02302961) commit (i.e. ninja 1.9.0), the environment variable `CLICOLOR_FORCE` can be used to disable stripping color codes.